# SpriteKit - font not found

Tags: swift, xcode, fonts, sprite-kit, truetype

I am developing for macOS and I would like to use a custom TTF font with SKLabelNode in my SpriteKit project.
I did search the web how to do it and every place I can find describe the following steps:

1. Add the font to your app bundle
2. Add the "Application fonts resource path" key to Info.plist with
   "Fonts" as the value
3. Add the "Fonts provided by application" key to Info.plist and add name of the font file
4. Create a Copy build phase with "Resources" as the Destination and
   "Fonts" as the Subpath
5. Drag/Drop the font to the Copy build phase
6. In Finder right-click on the font file and select the "Get Info" menu option.
   From the "Full Name" field, copy the font's name

I have done everything from the list above and I try to set the font inside the didMove() method programatically like so:

```
titleLabel = self.childNode(withName: "TitleLabel") as! SKLabelNode
titleLabel.fontName = "Lobster Regular"
```

However, when I run it, I get the error "Lobster Regular" font is not found. I double checked and this is the name of the font. I also tried to use the file name but that also did not worked.

I did also follow the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/text_display_and_fonts/adding_a_custom_font_to_your_app).
The problem is however, the documentation suggest that after adding the font to the Xcode project and include the keys in info.plist, I should be able to assign the font to labels using interface builder. But in my case, the font does not show up inside interface builder.

If I add the font to Font Book, it works, I can use it both programatically and inside interface builder but I would like to include the font with my app/game instead.

What am I missing? Is there any other properties in Xcode I should check?

Thank you.

Comment: One cannot tell for which OS you are developing your game.

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks for the warning, did not know it is makes a difference, I am developing for macOS.

Comment: The ways you use custom fonts are different between iOS and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

It seems in my case the solution was to set the "Application fonts resource path" key to an empty string, just leave it blank the value field to automatically pick up all fonts I have included with the project. Entering a . as value also seems to work and able to set the font programatically this way.